# Почему метод `draw` не рисует?

Tags: java

В общем хотел в `main` методе создать объект класса `Main`, в конструкторе которого создаётся `JFrame` окошко, далее запускается метод `run`, в котором в течении 5 сек выполняется метод `draw`, который рисует в окошке... Что изменить в конструкторе или методе `run` чтобы `draw` работал?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        System.out.println("Прошло 5 сек");
    }

    //Переменные
    public final static String name = "TEST"; //Название
    public static final int WIDTH = 600; //ШИРИНА
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600; //ВЫСОТА

    private Date x;
    private Date endTime;

    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private Graphics2D g =(Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

    private boolean fourSec = true; //Цикл

    //Конструктор
    public Main() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame(name);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        f.setFocusable(false);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        run();
        f.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        x = new Date();
        long xPlusFourSec = x.getTime() + 5000;
        endTime = new Date(xPlusFourSec);

        while (fourSec) {
            if (!x.after(endTime)) {
                x = new Date();
                upDate();
                draw(g);
                System.out.println(endTime.getTime() - x.getTime());
            } else {
                fourSec = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH / 2, WIDTH / 2);
        g.drawString("TEST STRING", WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
    }

    public void upDate() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Этот метод рисует. Он рисует на картинке `image`:

```
private Graphics2D g =(Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
```

А для рисования в окошке надо получить Graphics2D из окошка. Ищите способы в документации.

А еще лучше - унаследоваться от JFrame и перегрузить метод рисования, тогда не придется крутить цикл.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробую что-нибудь поискать, хоть я и не совсем понял. Я думал, что g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); как раз и накладывает картинку на фрейм, а на картинке уже можно рисовать.

Comment: @Даня он *накладывал бы* картинку на фрейм, *если бы* объект `g` был создан с фрейма. Но сейчас он рисует картинку на этой же картинке.